# ASP .NET accessing data of Gridview row and invoke procedure for a buttonfield coulmn row

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am creating a simple web application.
But I am facing a problem with a Gridview that displays some data from the database in a column and i have another column with a buttons where I want to invoke a stored procedure.
However the stored procedure takes as input the value of the corresponding data in the other column, so my question is how to access the value of this column and pass it to the action listener of the corresponding buttonfield?

Comment: Which Column.. you must be more specific is this a single grid view or a Relational gridview..? what code event do you have.. you must get a the row and from there the cell

Comment: single grid view with 2 columns as follows data column and buttons column. I want to pass the data of the data column to the listener of the button column.

Comment: good suggestion from Rondel but it's really hard to recommend something without seeing what you have tried.. accessing the columns is not hard .. are you using {Binding}, RecordSet, DataSet, linq...ect.. need more of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it up as a Template field in the aspx page and pass in the Value of the field you want as an argument:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd" OnRowCommand="grd_RowCommand">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click" CommandName="Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FirstColumnFieldName") %>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And then in your code behind, you could do this:

```
protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
switch (e.CommandName)
{
    case "Click":
    {
        string FirstColumnValue = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        hiddenfield.Value = FirstColumnValue;
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

You can find more solutions [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/116141/Get-Column-value-from-grid-on-link-button-click-ev)